# Disable scrolling of viewport when writing in input field or textarea?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to disable the auto scrolling (that happens when the caret gets out of the view) of the viewport when entering text in to an input field or textarea?

In other words: when the input field is very long or positioned absolutely at the border of the viewport and you type in an input field, the parent div will scroll to get the current caret into the viewport.

Try writing a long text into the inputfield in the fiddle to see what I mean.

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jg19s00t/)**

**HTML:**

```html
<div style="position:absolute;left:200px;width:5000px">
    <div><textarea style="width:120%">Test</textarea></div>
    <div><input type="test" style="width:120%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: _Why_ would you want this? It looks like that would be a serious setback in terms of usability.

Comment: It's to be used in a fullscreen Leaflet map where the user adds markers to the map and where the marker popup contains an input field. I don't want the map to move if you position a marker on the edge of the map and starts typing.

Comment: So you rather want the user not to see what they are typing?

Comment: Your problem has absolutely nothing to do with Leaflet.